# Checkbox does not appear until hover to the installer

Tags: installation, nsis

I added the "Create Desktop Shortcut" checkbox to the finish page. However, the check box did not appear (as image 1) until I hook the installer. And when the check box appears, the entire page is completed will disappear (as image 2).

[image: Finish page]
[image: Checkbox]

This is the code I use:

```
;--------------------------------
; Include Modern UI
;--------------------------------
Unicode true
!include "MUI.nsh"
;--------------------------------
; General
;--------------------------------
;Name and file
Name "Test blah"
OutFile "BlahInstaller.exe"

;Default installation folder
Function .onInit
    StrCpy "$INSTDIR" "$EXEDIR" 2
    StrCpy "$INSTDIR" "$INSTDIR\Blah"
FunctionEnd

; Get installation folder from registry if available
InstallDirRegKey HKCU "Software\Blah Blah" ""

!define VERSION "1.0.0.0"
VIProductVersion "${VERSION}"
VIFileVersion "${VERSION}"
VIAddVersionKey "FileVersion" "${VERSION}"
VIAddVersionKey "LegalCopyright" "(C) Blah blah Inc."
VIAddVersionKey "FileDescription" "Blah blah blergh fancy app"

;--------------------------------
; Interface Settings
;--------------------------------
;!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
;!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
;!define MUI_ICON                       "icon.ico"
;!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP         "installer-header.bmp"
;!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_UNBITMAP       "installer-header.bmp"
;!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP   "installer-wizard.bmp"
;!define MUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "installer-wizard.bmp"

;--------------------------------
; Pages
;--------------------------------
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

;------------------------------
; Finish Page
;------------------------------

; Checkbox for Create Desktop Shortcut.
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE CreateControls
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW SetControlColours
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE CreateDesktopShortcut
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

;--------------------------------
; Languages
;--------------------------------
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

;--------------------------------
; Installer Sections
;--------------------------------
Section "installer"
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

    ;File /r *.*

    WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Blah" "" $INSTDIR

    WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"
SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
; Uninstaller Section
;--------------------------------
Section "Uninstall"
    ; Remove all files in install forder
    Delete "$INSTDIR\*.*"

    Delete "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

    DeleteRegKey HKCU "Software\Blah"

    ; Remove install forder
    RMDir "$INSTDIR"
SectionEnd

;-----------------------------------------------------------------
;  The following two functions CreateControls & SetControlColours
;  are editing the ini file at runtime so we can add the additional
;  check box.
;-----------------------------------------------------------------

Function CreateControls
    ; Desktop shortcut.
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Settings" "NumFields" "7"
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "Type" "CheckBox"
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "Text" "&Create Desktop Shortcut"
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "Left" "120"
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "Right" "315"
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "Bottom" "180"
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "State" "1"
FunctionEnd

Function SetControlColours
    ReadINIStr $0 "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "HWND"
    SetCtlColors $0 0x000000 0xFFFFFF
FunctionEnd

Function CreateDesktopShortcut
    ;CreateShortcut "$desktop\blah.lnk" "$instdir\blah.exe"
FunctionEnd
```

Why does the check box not appear with the installation page complete? How do I do them at the same time?

Comment: Which NSIS version?

Comment: @Anders I'm using NSIS version 3.08.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the "..has been installed ..." label is overlapping your checkbox. Your checkbox also goes all the way to the top because you failed to specify the "top" .ini value!

The easy solution is to just use one of the checkboxes provided by MUI instead:

```
...
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN 
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_TEXT "&Create Desktop Shortcut"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION CreateDesktopShortcut
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
...
```

If you absolutely want to use a custom checkbox you have to adjust the conflicting label:

```
Function CreateControls
    ; Desktop shortcut.
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Settings" "NumFields" "7"
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 3" "Bottom" "100" ; Prevent overlapping
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "Type" "CheckBox"
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "Text" "&Create Desktop Shortcut"
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "Left" "120"
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "Right" "315"
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "Top" "100" ; Must be >= Field 3 bottom
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "Bottom" "120"
    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\iospecial.ini" "Field 7" "State" "1"
FunctionEnd
```